# Redireccionar despues del login

Tags: php, mysqli, login, redirección

Buen día, hoy es un domingo 'brillante' por acá. 
Así que no les haré perder demasiado tiempo. 
Toda la primera parte funciona estupendo. 
El problema es cuando aparece SWITCH. ahí ni verifica que esté bien logueado pero sí me envía a la pagina del case. 
Por lo que supongo que el problema está entre **intentarlo"; { switch ($grupo) {** Va código completo EDITADO

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
require('90_0encab.inc');
require('92_0musr.inc');
include('99_conn.php');
if(isset($_POST['bt-011']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $clave = $_POST['clave'];
    $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
    $error = '';
    //$sha1_pass = sha1($password);

    $sql011 = "SELECT 98_idusr, 98_username, 98_clave, 98_grupo FROM $t98 WHERE 98_username = '$username' AND 98_clave = '$clave' AND 98_grupo = '$grupo'";
    $res011 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql011);
        $rows=$res011->num_rows;
        if ($rows > 0) 
            $row = $res011->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['98_idusr'] = $row['98_idusr'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']; 
            $_SESSION['clave'] = $row['clave'];
            $_SESSION['grupo'] = $row['grupo'];
            //echo "true";
            $error= "El nombre de usuario o clave es incorrecto, Por favor vuelva a intentarlo";
//{
    switch ($grupo) {
        case '1':   header('location: Index_dir.php');  break;
        case '2':   header('location: Index_adm.php');  break;
        case '3':   header('location: Index_ori.php');  break;
        case '4':   header('location: Index_eva.php');  break;
        case '5':   header('location: Index_con.php');  break;
        case '6':   header('location: Index_root.php'); break;
        default:    header('location: Index.html');     break;
//  }
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
}
?>
```

**De donde sale el grupo**
........

```
<tr><td align="center"><select name="grupo" id="grupo" title="grupo" width=200>
            <option value="1">direccion</option>
            <option value="2">administracion</option>
            <option value="3">orientador</option>
            <option value="4">evaluador</option>
            <option value="5">invitado</option>
            <option value="6">root</option>
    </select> </td></tr>
..........
```

Espero que alguien con más conocimientos (debe haber muchisimos por acá) que yo me de una manito con el colapso. GRACIAS!!!

Comment: No entendi bien tu problema. Se ejecuta el switch? Ocurre algun error? Que es lo que esta fallando?

Comment: Como dice Einer explica mejor el error que tienes y si te sale algún mensaje copialo para poder tener más pistas sobre lo que puede pasar. Ten en cuenta también que al realizar diversas pruebas la primera vez ya se crea variable de session y esta permanece si no la borras en otro lado así si hay un error no lo visualizarás muy bien, puede inducir a error. También el echo "true" si no me equivoco para que se envíe el header no se debe escribir antes nada por pantalla de modo que cuando realice el echo dará error al ejecutar el header, no te ocurre esto?

Comment: Primero: gracias por las prontas respuestas!
a) tal vez no me haya explicado suficientemente bien, si yo no incluyo la parte del switch, me logueo perfecto y me dirige a las muy pocas posibilidades que puede haber 1) si es correcto a cualquier index que me parezca oportuno 2) al html que es como un rechazado, volvé a intentar, no puse todo eso porque no es mi problema
b) cuando agrego el switch a la rutina no le interesa si me logueo bien o mal, no lo registra, directamente me envía a la pagina del switch correspondiente así haya escrito username xxx clave xxxd que obviamente no existen

Comment: No es un problema de variables de sesion eso lo verifiqué varias veces en la 1º parte del código hasta el mugroso SWITCH

Comment: Te haré dos preguntas: **1.** ¿La variable `$grupo` que quieres evalúar en el `switch` es la que recibes en el POST o es la que obtienes en la consulta a la BD? En cualquier caso, ¿estás seguro de que esa variable tiene datos, la has depurado? **2.** La doc dice esto: _Recuerde que `header()` debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde PHP._ Es decir, no puedes usar `header(location...)` si antes has sacado algo por pantalla con `echo`, por HTML u otros. Me parece que eso no se cumple en tu código, pues tienes `echo "true";`

Comment: puedo intentar hacer lo del echo que proponés, de hecho está ahí desde el logueo perfecto.
La variable $grupo viene del logueo (username, clave, grupo) lo único que aparece por el $row como nuevo es el $idusr que viene de la linea verificada en el logueo y directamente por el $row asignandole el nombre de campo del renglón logueado correctamente (username, clave, grupo) que son POST del formulario.
Si me aconsejas retirar el echo dalo por hecho, ahora lo intento.

Comment: Por otra parte, esa forma de usar las `{` la verdad no la entiendo... Por ejemplo, la `{` que está antes del `switch`, **¿qué bloque está abriendo realmente?**  Sinceramente PHP es algo desastroso en eso, pero yo no alcanzo a escribir código así, ni entiendo el código cuando se escribe sin abrir y cerrar todo. ¿El `if ($rows > 0)` dónde se abre y dónde se cierra?

Comment: estoy de acuerdo QUE LAS { } NO EXISTAN MAS
Pero ya desistí de pelear con quienes dicen saber de codigo. Yo era tan feliz con el DW 8 (carita triste) y estoy tan enfurecida con el DW2017 que no sabe hacer código ni viejo mirá!
ya la borré a la { previa al switch y eliminé el echo y también la } de cierre y sabés que ocurre, nada, ni te manda al demonio por loguearte mal y te sigue enviando directamente al Index que hayas elegido durante el logueo, o sea no le interesa si sos usuario y adm(INISTRATIVO) te manda a ADM porque le caiste simpatico aunque no seas usuario registrado

Comment: El responsable del código eres tú, no el programa. A ver: [Edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/104647/edit) poniendo el código como lo tienes ahora. Y sólo dime si el `switch` tiene que ir dentro del bloque del `if ($rows > 0)...` o no, porque es que no lo entiendo de verdad.  Y también dime si depuraste el valor de `$grupo`.

Comment: No iría al chat salvo por indicación de quien está conversando conmigo, si el no me lo propone, creo que puedo seguir aqui, salvo que no esté permitido o esté prohibido! Gracias

Comment: Ahí lo edité, creo que estaba ahí como alternativa al if, pero todavía no se indentar bien, por lo que acepto cualquier crítica constructiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver si así funciona.

Si no funciona, comenta el resultado.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    if(isset($_POST['bt-011']))
    {
        require('90_0encab.inc');
        require('92_0musr.inc');
        include('99_conn.php');
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $clave = $_POST['clave'];
        $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
        $error = '';
        $sql011 = "SELECT 98_idusr, 98_username, 98_clave, 98_grupo FROM $t98 WHERE 98_username = '$username' AND 98_clave = '$clave' AND 98_grupo = '$grupo'";
        $res011 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql011);
        $rows=$res011->num_rows;
        if ($rows > 0) {
                $row = $res011->fetch_assoc();
                $_SESSION['98_idusr'] = $row['98_idusr'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']; 
                $_SESSION['clave'] = $row['clave'];
                $_SESSION['grupo'] = $row['grupo'];
                $error= "El nombre de usuario o clave es incorrecto, Por favor vuelva a intentarlo";
                if ($grupo) 
                {
                    switch ($grupo) 
                    {
                        case '1':   header('location: Index_dir.php');  break;
                        case '2':   header('location: Index_adm.php');  break;
                        case '3':   header('location: Index_ori.php');  break;
                        case '4':   header('location: Index_eva.php');  break;
                        case '5':   header('location: Index_con.php');  break;
                        case '6':   header('location: Index_root.php'); break;
                        default:    header('location: Index.html');     break;
                  }
              }else{
                echo "La variable grupo no tiene datos";                
              }
        }else{
                echo "No se encontraron registros. Puedes cambiar esto por un header(location...) si lo deseas";
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    } else {
    echo "El valor bt-011  no fue posteado";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sí funciona, redirige donde corresponde y se niega a enviarme a ninguna parte si no me logueo correctamente, podría decirte que sos un genio?
Se que son muy humildes así que MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!!!!!!

Comment: bt-011 es el nombre del boton enviar.
y voy seguramente a subir las require que son respectivamente el encabezado y el menu de la página, supongo que no alterará en nada, espero. Gracias muchas, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes redireccionar fácilmente a la página de inicio de sesión utilizando la función integrada en PHP: `header()`

Revisé tu código y puedo apreciar que estás escribiendo las condiciones *en línea*, te sugiero enormemente utilizar los paréntesis `{` y `}`, ya que PHP tiene algunos problemas si no mencionas el cuerpo de una condición.

Comment: @SilviaGaviotaGarcia Si no quieres añadir los paréntesis en el cuerpo de la condición, entonces toma un salto de línea por cada condición para que el interpretador de PHP sepa al 100% que la condición esta *en línea*.

Comment: para que nos entendamos, el if es una condicion OK 
puedo añadir tantos paréntesis, corchetes o llaves como me propongas. Para mí es que sin la parte del switch me reconoce como usuario con todas mis características, yo soy root, mi gata es orientadora y mi marido director.(de las variables de sesion) 
Pero al poner el switch todo y digo todo, empezando por la sesion desaparece, puedo poner a mi perro como director y me direcciona a la pagina de mi marido, o poner al pajarito del vecino y si le digo que es adm va a esa pagina cuando ni siquiera está el avecita en la bbdd,se entiende?

Comment: Tu gata es orientadora?  Qué estas construyendo?

Comment: sólo el uso de diferentes usuarios que yo manejo, no seas malo! jajajaj

Comment: ¿Esto es en serio o es todo una broma @SilviaGaviotaGarcia? Los comentarios no encajan con la realidad del problema, espero que no estés haciendo perder el tiempo a gente que intenta ayudarte.

Comment: @AntonioRamos completa el [tour] para obtener una idea de cómo funciona el sitio. Aquí no se ofrecen trabajos ni servicios, y hay que ser respetuoso con el resto de usuarios.